# Single Workspace VPN

Tags: 18.04, vpn, workspaces, workspace-switcher

I've struggled to find a definitive answer, and I've tried some alternative solutions (to no avail); But one mentioned using a VM which made me think of workspaces.  I've never used workspaces before and have no idea how they work and what they are for.  If my question is actually possible, if someone could point me to a trusted source to learn how to use workspaces, I'd appreciate it.

My question is related to using a VPN for some programs some of the time, but also to have some programs run outside of the VPN (directly through my router); some progs are on permanently, some are just on as i use them.

One of the problems i have is that in general i want to use Chrome through the VPN, but there are also times I'll want it to bypass the VPN and just use my router, (just in case it doesn't allow the same program running in two workspaces independently).

The basic (but not complete) requirements are having torrents run through the VPN, (and sometimes Chrome and other progs i use).  And I run a Plex server from the same machine which I'd need to function outside the vpn, (and occasionally use Chrome and other progs randomly).

I'm using PrivateInternetAccess for my VPN services if that's important.  And I'm running 18.04 LTS with the Gnome3 it comes with.